# Clojure: Semi-Flattening a nested Sequence

Tags: clojure, sequence

I have a list with embedded lists of vectors, which looks like:

`(([1 2]) ([3 4] [5 6]) ([7 8]))`

Which I know is not ideal to work with. I'd like to flatten this to `([1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8])`.

flatten doesn't work: it gives me `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)`.

How do I do this?  I figure I need to create a new list based on the *contents* of each list item, not the items, and it's this part I can't find out how to do from the docs.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you only want to flatten it one level you can use `concat`

```
(apply concat '(([1 2]) ([3 4] [5 6]) ([7 8])))
=> ([1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8])
```

Answer (score 28):

To turn a list-of-lists into a single list containing the elements of every sub-list, you want `apply concat` as nickik suggests.

However, there's usually a better solution: don't produce the list-of-lists to begin with! For example, let's imagine you have a function called `get-names-for` which takes a symbol and returns a list of all the cool things you could call that symbol:

```
(get-names-for '+) => (plus add cross junction)
```

If you want to get all the names for some list of symbols, you might try

```
(map get-names-for '[+ /]) 
=> ((plus add cross junction) (slash divide stroke))
```

But this leads to the problem you were having. You could glue them together with an `apply concat`, but better would be to use `mapcat` instead of `map` to begin with:

```
(mapcat get-names-for '[+ /]) 
=> (plus add cross junction slash divide stroke)
```

Comment: yea +1 for mapcat -- it led to a MUCH more elegant solution than i would have had otherwise. very good to know. thanks!

Comment: I am using `map-indexed`, though and there is no `mapcat-indexed`

Comment: @PostSelf `map-indexed` is just a shorthand for adding an argument to `map`. Instead of `(apply concat (map-indexed f xs))`, try `(mapcat f (range) xs)`.

Comment: @amalloy That's awesome! I realized that I do a `filter` based on the second element of each pair, so unless there's a way of incorporating that, I have to leave it as is

Comment: @PostSelf There is, of course! `mapcat` is sorta a "fundamental" list operation on which many others can be built. Instead of `(apply concat (filter (comp pred second) (map-indexed f xs)))`, you can write `(mapcat (fn [i x] (let [x' (f x)] (when (pred x') [i x']))) (range) xs)`.

Comment: `mapcat` is the MVP.

Answer (score 9):

The code for `flatten` is fairly short:

```
(defn flatten
  [x]
  (filter (complement sequential?)
    (rest (tree-seq sequential? seq x))))
```

It uses `tree-seq` to walk through the data structure and return a sequence of the atoms. Since we want all the bottom-level sequences, we could modify it like this:

```
(defn almost-flatten
  [x]
  (filter #(and (sequential? %) (not-any? sequential? %))
    (rest (tree-seq #(and (sequential? %) (some sequential? %)) seq x))))
```

so we return all the sequences that don't contain sequences.

Comment: `(def balls '((:a 1) ((:b 1) (:c 1))))`

Not exactly:
(apply concat balls)
=> (:a 1 (:b 1) (:c 1))

Perfect:
(almost-flatten balls)
=> ((:a 1) (:b 1) (:c 1))

Answer (score 4):

Also you may found useful this general 1 level flatten function I found on [clojuremvc](https://github.com/michelvollebregt/clojuremvc/blob/master/src/org/clojuremvc/list_util.clj#L4):

```
(defn flatten-1 
  "Flattens only the first level of a given sequence, e.g. [[1 2][3]] becomes
   [1 2 3], but [[1 [2]] [3]] becomes [1 [2] 3]."
  [seq]
  (if (or (not (seqable? seq)) (nil? seq))
    seq ; if seq is nil or not a sequence, don't do anything
    (loop [acc [] [elt & others] seq]
      (if (nil? elt) acc
        (recur
          (if (seqable? elt)
            (apply conj acc elt) ; if elt is a sequence, add each element of elt
            (conj acc elt))      ; if elt is not a sequence, add elt itself 
       others)))))
```

Example:

```
(flatten-1 (([1 2]) ([3 4] [5 6]) ([7 8])))
=>[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8]]
```

`concat` exampe surely do job for you, but this `flatten-1` is also **allowing non seq elements** inside a collection:

```
(flatten-1 '(1 2 ([3 4] [5 6]) ([7 8])))
=>[1 2 [3 4] [5 6] [7 8]]
;whereas 
(apply concat '(1 2 ([3 4] [5 6]) ([7 8])))
=> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
   Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that will flatten down to the sequence level, regardless of uneven nesting:

```
(fn flt [s] (mapcat #(if (every? coll? %) (flt %) (list %)) s))
```

So if your original sequence was:

```
'(([1 2]) (([3 4]) ((([5 6])))) ([7 8]))
```

You'd still get the same result:

```
([1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8])
```