# What's the one-level sequence flattening function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

What's the one-level sequence flattening function in Clojure? I am using `apply concat` for now, but I wonder if there is a built-in function for that, either in standard library or clojure-contrib.

Comment: maybe this is a dup of the link i give in my answer?  will vote to close if no-one turns up anything better soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5232350/425313

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My general first choice is `apply concat`. Also, don't overlook `(for [subcoll coll, item subcoll] item)` -- depending on the broader context, this may result in clearer code.

Comment: Okay, I think `mapcat identity` was what I needed. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: mapcat is implemented as apply concat https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2652, which is lazy through the magic of handling args as a sequence.

Answer (score 22):

There's no standard function. `apply concat` is a good solution in many cases. Or you can equivalently use `mapcat seq`.

The problem with `apply concat` is that it fails when there is anything other than a collection/sequential is at the first level:

```
(apply concat [1 [2 3] [4 [5]]])
=> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long...
```

Hence you may want to do something like:

```
(defn flatten-one-level [coll]  
  (mapcat  #(if (sequential? %) % [%]) coll))

(flatten-one-level [1 [2 3] [4 [5]]])
=> (1 2 3 4 [5])
```

As a more general point, the lack of a built-in function should not usually stop you from defining your own :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want the behavior that's given by `apply concat`.

Answer (score 10):

i use `apply concat` too - i don't think there's anything else in the core.

`flatten` is multiple levels (and is defined via a tree-walk, not in terms of repeated single level expansion)

see also [Clojure: Semi-Flattening a nested Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232350/clojure-semi-flattening-a-nested-sequence) which has a `flatten-1` from [clojure mvc](https://github.com/michelvollebregt/clojuremvc/blob/master/src/org/clojuremvc/list_util.clj#L4) (and which is much more complex than i expected).

*update* to clarify laziness:

```
user=> (take 3 (apply concat (for [i (range 1e6)] (do (print i) [i]))))
012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031(0 1 2)
```

you can see that it evaluates the argument 32 times - this is chunking for efficiency, and is otherwise lazy (it doesn't evaluate the whole list).  for a discussion of chunking see comments at end of http://isti.bitbucket.org/2012/04/01/pipes-clojure-choco-1.html

Comment: I gather `apply` should be used rarely? Is this usage justified? Isn't it slower than necessary?

Comment: the only reason i can think for saying it should be used rarely is that if a single alternative exists then it should be used.  as for speed, i have no idea, but don't expect it to be particularly slow.

Comment: It's definitely not the case that apply should be used rarely. Use it all you want; sprinkle it liberally on your pasta, whatever. Sequences are lazy, including function-arg sequences, so `(apply (fn [& args] (first args)) (range 1e5))` is still very fast, just passing the function a pointer to the start of the list. `concat` has a similar "shape" so it's just as cheap.

Comment: It's worth knowing that apply realizes a minimum of 4 elements, even without chunking. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51959298/172272