# Clojure apply that does not realize the first four elements of a lazy sequence?

Tags: clojure

It appears that apply forces the realization of four elements given a lazy sequence.

```
(take 1
      (apply concat
             (repeatedly #(do
                            (println "called")
                            (range 1 10)))))

=> "called"
=> "called"
=> "called"
=> "called"
```

Is there a way to do an apply which does not behave this way?

Thank You

Comment: @akond That's what I thought at first also, but this isn't due to chunking as far as I can tell, but it's because of apply realizing the first four, and one extra afterwards.

Comment: Right, I discovered this by using short ranges: `(range 1 5)`. The result didn't change.

Comment: Looks like there are two open JIRAs for this: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1583 and https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1218

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do an `apply` which does not behave this way?

I think the short answer is: not without reimplementing some of Clojure's basic functionality. `apply`'s implementation relies directly on Clojure's implementation of callable functions, and tries to discover the proper arity of the given function to `.invoke` by enumerating the input sequence of arguments.

It may be easier to factor your solution using functions over lazy, un-chunked sequences / reducers / transducers, rather than using variadic functions with `apply`. For example, here's your sample reimplemented with transducers and it only invokes the body function once (per length of `range`):

```
(sequence
  (comp
    (mapcat identity)
    (take 1))
  (repeatedly #(do
                 (println "called")
                 (range 1 10))))
;; called
;; => (1)
```

Digging into what's happening in your example with `apply`, `concat`, `seq`, `LazySeq`, etc.:

- `repeatedly` returns a new `LazySeq` instance: `(lazy-seq (cons (f) (repeatedly f)))`.
- For the given 2-arity `(apply concat <args>)`, `apply` calls `RT.seq` on its argument list, which for a `LazySeq` then invokes [`LazySeq.seq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L528), which will invoke your function
- `apply` then calls a Java impl. method [`applyToHelper`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java#L147) which tries to get the length of the argument sequence. `applyToHelper` tries to determine the length of the argument list using `RT.boundedLength`, which internally calls `next` and in turn `seq`, so it can find the [proper overload of `IFn.invoke`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/71511b7800e18c83377a322f43585a853b303698/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java#L25-L93) to call
- `concat` itself adds another layer of `lazy-seq` behavior.

You can see the stack traces of these invocations like this:

```
(take 1
  (repeatedly #(do
                 (clojure.stacktrace/print-stack-trace (Exception.))
                 (range 1 10))))
```

The first trace descends from the `apply`'s initial call to `seq`, and the subsequent traces from `RT.boundedLength`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. My problem is, I need it to be lazy, because it's an infinite sequence over a remote queue. Do you have any idea in that case how to avoid the apply?

Comment: Also iterate can be relied upon to always short circuit properly. Just thought I'd mention it as another, sometimes simpler solution than "functions over lazy, un-chunked sequences / reducers / transducers".

Comment: Just FYI: There is a JIRA ticket for this. I can't find it right now though. The ticket is pretty old.

Answer (score 2):

in fact, your code doesn't realize any of the items from the concatenated collections (ranges in your case). So the resulting collection is truly lazy as far as elements are concerned. The prints you get are from the function calls, generating unrealized lazy seqs. This one could easily be checked this way:

```
(defn range-logged [a b]
  (lazy-seq
   (when (< a b)
     (println "realizing item" a)
     (cons a (range-logged (inc a) b)))))

user> (take 1
            (apply concat
                   (repeatedly #(do
                                  (println "called")
                                  (range-logged 1 10)))))

;;=> called
;;   called
;;   called
;;   called
;;   realizing item 1
(1)

user> (take 10
            (apply concat
                   (repeatedly #(do
                                  (println "called")
                                  (range-logged 1 10)))))
;; called
;; called
;; called
;; called
;; realizing item 1
;; realizing item 2
;; realizing item 3
;; realizing item 4
;; realizing item 5
;; realizing item 6
;; realizing item 7
;; realizing item 8
;; realizing item 9
;; realizing item 1
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1)
```

So my guess is that you have nothing to worry about, as long as the collection returned from `repeatedly` closure is lazy

Comment: I think yes in the case of repeatedly, but this isn't true always, for example with mapcat it will realize the elements due to its use of apply under the hood.