# Merging maps without overriding keys

Tags: clojure

I have a clojure function that returns a sequence of 1-key maps. I want to merge these maps into one map; however, if there are maps with the same key, I don't want to overwrite the values, only to combine them into a vector. `merge` seems to overwrite, and `merge-with` seems to seriously distort the type.

I have:

```
({:foo "hello"}
 {:bar "world"} 
 {:baz "!!!"}
 {:ball {:a "abc", :b "123"}}
 {:ball {:a "def", :b "456"}}
 {:ball {:a "ghi", :b "789"}})
```

I'd like:

```
{:foo "hello"
 :bar "world"
 :baz "!!!"
 :ball [{:a "abc", :b "123"} {:a "def", :b "456"} {:a "ghi", :b "789"}]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to do this, but I'd step back and ask why? What's the use of having a map where values could be either scalars or vectors depending on whether there was a duplicate? A map with consistent value types will be much easier to work with.

Comment: I'm dealing with a java backend. Its types are not apart of my control.

Comment: [This section](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-22_multiple-values/2-22_multiple-values.asciidoc) of the [Clojure Cookbook](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fclojure-cookbook.com%2F) deals with having single and multiple values in the same map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(def data ...) ;; your list of maps

(apply merge-with (comp flatten vector) data)
;; => {:baz "!!!", :ball ({:b "123", :a "abc"} {:b "456", :a "def"} {:b "789", :a "ghi"}), :bar "world", :foo "hello"}
```

**Note:** the use of `flatten` works in OP's case but is NOT a general way to merge maps while creating vectors of values belonging to colliding keys.

Comment: Better hope that none of the values being merged are vectors.

Comment: yeah... flatten is almost guranteed to not do what you want :/

Comment: @arrdem if OP doesn't know what data is returned, then yes, flatten is not the way to go. Could either of you add an answer that better fits the general case?

Comment: Not clever enough to see if its a solution, but I got a lot of use out of `almost-flatten` and `flatten-1`, referenced here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232350/clojure-semi-flattening-a-nested-sequence .

Answer (score 1):

The "vector-safe" variant I could come up with has to iterate over all key-value-pairs twice:

```
(->> (for [[k vs] (group-by key (apply concat data))]
       (if (next vs)
         [k (mapv val vs)]
         (first vs)))
     (into {}))
;; => {:foo "hello",
;;     :bar "world",
;;     :baz "!!!",
;;     :ball [{:a "abc", :b "123"} ...]}
```

Basically, this groups all values by key and only removes the seq around them if it contains exactly one element.

---

The fully threaded version (for readability):

```
(->> (apply concat data)
     (group-by key)
     (map
       (fn [[k vs]]
         (if (next vs)
           [k (mapv val vs)]
           (first vs))))
     (into {}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a predictable type for each key would save you headaches when you want to read it back later, but if you have no other choice: `merge-with` with a custom function would solve it:

```
(apply merge-with (fn [v1 v2] ((if (vector? v1) conj vector) v1 v2)) data)
```