# How to generate one lazy sequence from a nested for loop in Clojure

Tags: for-loop, clojure, lazy-sequences

This is a question about how to properly collect the results from a nested `for` loop in Clojure. Suppose you want to create a sequence of all vectors `[i j]` where `0<=j<i<4`

The following code

```
(for [i (range 1 4)] 
  (for [j (range i)] 
     [i j]
  )
)
```

produces

```
(([1 0]) ([2 0] [2 1]) ([3 0] [3 1] [3 2]))
```

but what I really want to get is

```
([1 0] [2 0] [2 1] [3 0] [3 1] [3 2])
```

What is the right way to do this?

Notice that I'm not interested in this specific sequence. My purpose here is to learn how to collect results from a nested `for` loop, which I need for a more complex problem.

Comment: FYI `for` in Clojure is not like `for` in C or Java. Having a for nested in an other for is rather unusual. Clojure `for` is a list comprehension function, it helps you create a list. See Python list comprehension for [exemples](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the approach you are suggesting and it it really cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't nest two loops, rather use one loop with two iterators:

```
(for [i (range 1 4)
      j (range i)] 
   [i j])
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you *have* to use nested for loops, `apply concat` is the [preferred way to flatten a sequence by one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232350/clojure-semi-flattening-a-nested-sequence)

```
=> (apply concat 
         (for [i (range 1 4)] 
           (for [j (range i)] 
             [i j])))

([1 0] [2 0] [2 1] [3 0] [3 1] [3 2])
```

[@Oin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120416/how-to-generate-one-lazy-sequence-from-a-nested-for-loop-in-clojure/35120468#35120468) is always preferable, unless the inner loop depends on the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.